# column: line too long error

Tags: command-line, text-processing, csv

I'm trying to view the first 5 columns from the terminal following this guide here: 
https://chrisjean.com/view-csv-data-from-the-command-line/

When I run

```
cat rangelast.csv | sed -e 's/,,/, ,/g' | column -s, -t | less -#5 -N -S
```

I get this error:

```
column: line too long
```

How can I solve it?

Comment: with `column`, always also make sure that ALL LINES (especially the final line) end in a newline.  You will see the `line too long` (even on a short line) if the final line does not terminate with `\n`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to [this bug report](https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=737348)

In the utility source code: `column.c` It defines `MAXLINELEN as 2048 + 1`

If your input contains a line which its length is > 2048 you'll get this error.

In order to solve it, you should make sure that the length of the lines in your input is < 2048, or replace the 'column' utility with another one.

Comment: what 'column' utility should i use ?

Comment: @QassamMahmoud - this is another question, if you like, you can open a new question, define your input, the desired manipulation on the input/expected output. and asked for help.

Comment: @QassamMahmoud if the task is important enough... you can get the source and build from source and just change the constant value from 2048 to 2,4,8,16,32 times the size.